# Adding attributes to xelements of existing xml

Tags: c#, xml

This is my code:

```
var nodes = XDocument.Parse(gridxml).Root.Elements();
                    var attribute = new XAttribute("open", "0");
                    foreach (var node in nodes)
                    {
                        node.Add(attribute);
                    }
```

When I check the value of the nodes in debug mode, I see that all of them have the open attribute. However, when I check the value of gridxml, the elements don't have the open attribute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you check the value of `gridxml`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos In debug mode, I "watch" its value after the above code is executed

Comment: `gridxml` should be just a string constant. How do you expect it to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gridxml` in you example is a `String` which you are never modifying. `XDocument` is not an XML-friendly `String` wrapper, it is a separate object, which has no influence over the `String` it was initialized from.

You should be checking `xdoc.ToString()` instead of `gridxml`. If for some reason you need to have the updated contents in your original variable, do `gridxml = xdoc.ToString()` after adding the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding attributes to copies of the nodes, try this:

```
        string gridxml = "<node1><node2></node2><node3></node3></node1>";

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(gridxml);
        var attribute = new XAttribute("open", "0");

        foreach (var node in xdoc.Root.Elements())
        {
            node.Add(attribute);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't think your code produces a different result compared to the result produced by the code of the OP.

Comment: My code shows parsing a string to an xdocument, adding attributes to the nodes, then outputting an amended document